# LiveDataScope emit not calling

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I am experiencing a very unusual problem where LiveDataScope is not throwing my Exception, launched in my repository.
The problem is that if in place of the emit, I put a livedata event, it is dispatched to the observer, however with emit, it does not launch the event to it.

**ViewModel:**

```
fun launchJob(makeThis: suspend LiveDataScope<ViewState>.() -> Unit): LiveData<ViewState> =
    liveData {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            emitLoad()
            try {
                makeThis(this@liveData)
            } catch (error: Error){
                //its work
                showErrorEvent.value = Pair(error, true)

                // not work
                emit(ViewState.Error(error))
            }
        }
    }
      viewmodel implementation
/**
 * Método responsável por realizar o método de reset de senha.
 * */
    fun requestReset() = launchJob {
         emitSucess(shippingMethodRepository.resetPassword(method))
    }
```

**base repository**

```
  suspend fun getAsyncData(params: P): T {
    try {
        return api.invoke(params)
    } catch (error: Exception) {
        error.printStackTrace()
        throw error
    }
}
```

As I mentioned, changing the emit to a different livedata, it is observed by the activity, and any code before the emit is read as well, as well as Log, etc.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs :

> The liveData building block serves as a structured concurrency
>   primitive between coroutines and LiveData. The code block starts
>   executing **when LiveData becomes active** and is automatically canceled
>   after a configurable timeout when the LiveData becomes inactive.

The root cause why your observer not triggered after called emit function is because your liveData has been observed (activated).

LiveData building block is more suitable for initialising liveData value than to change its value. If you want to change the liveData value like that, just use a mutableLiveData

Comment: Hi, thanks for listening.
So is a livedata builder for creations and not changes to livedata values? like a flow?

Comment: yes, it is like flow creation, but flow data changed can be observed by `collect()` function without the needs of lifeCycleOwner, which makes flow is not lifecycle aware

Comment: yes it makes sense, but in the issue of livedata scope, it was to be observed, making generic code, in try {} catc {} I can receive all emits, the problem would be in the catch of the repository.

Comment: Hi, see this line in docs:
It is also possible to issue multiple values ​​from the block. Each emit () call suspends the execution of the block until the LiveData value is defined in the main thread.